# How would I create a unique index on a per topic basis?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I need to create a unique anonymous index per user, per topic.  Each post doesn't start off with this index, but once a user edits a post to be anonymous, they are assigned their anonymous ID.  This means that the second poster of the topic is not always "Anonymous 2".

I've attempted to solve this problem with the code below, yet I am getting different posters with the same Anonymous index.

I am wondering, is there a better way to store these indexes and assure no repeating numbers per user, per topic?  Would I need to make a separate table?  Maybe use a unique constraint..?

I've thought that I could have a table with

-topic_id---anon_index-

structure or something, but then technically wouldn't there be a possibility of repeats?  And again, I already store this in the other posts table in its own column, anonymous_index.  I could just search for the max(anonymous_index) where $topic_id = some# or something like that without having to make a table.

I've been trying to design against making another table and relying off of the maximum anon index or the alternate (count(distinct(poster_id)) where anonymous_index > 0) that I do but obviously something here isn't right.

I call the function to get the anonymous index like so:

```
$data = $event['data'];
$username = $event['post_author_name'];

// get checkbox value
$anonpost = $event['post_data']['is_checked'];

$post_mode = $event['mode'];
$data['is_anonymous'] = $anonpost;
$data['was_anonymous'] = ($post_mode == 'edit') ? $event['post_data']['is_anonymous'] : 0;
$data['anonymous_index'] = ($post_mode == 'edit') ? $event['post_data']['anonymous_index'] : 0;

// fixed to return 1 for new topics, and mean it this time... wouldn't work sometimes for some weird reason
$get_anon_index = function() use($data, $post_mode)
{
        if($data['is_anonymous'])
                if($data['anonymous_index'] > 0) return $data['anonymous_index'];
                else return $this->helper->get_poster_index($data['topic_id'], $data['poster_id']);

        // 0 is default case... is default case really necessary?
        return (int) ($post_mode == 'post');
};

$data['anonymous_index'] = $get_anon_index();
```

and here's the get_poster_index function in my helper file that does the sql work:

```
// get unique poster index for consistent distinct anonymous posters
public function get_poster_index($topic_id, $poster_id)
{
    // have we already anonymously posted in this topic?
    // 0.7.0 - redundancy added (AND anonymous_index > 0)
    $anon_index_query = 'SELECT anonymous_index
                            FROM ' . POSTS_TABLE . "
                            WHERE topic_id = $topic_id
                            AND poster_id = $poster_id
                            AND anonymous_index > 0
                            ORDER BY post_time ASC LIMIT 1";

    $result = array();
    $result = $this->db->sql_query($anon_index_query);

    // these two get index of this post in that list
    $anonymous_index = (int) $this->db->sql_fetchfield('anonymous_index');

    $poster_index = $anonymous_index;
    $this->db->sql_freeresult($result);
    unset($result);

    // this only runs if we've never posted in this topic, having data from previous query...
    if($poster_index == 0)
    {
            $anon_index_query = 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(poster_id)) AS anon_index
                                    FROM ' . POSTS_TABLE . "
                                    WHERE (topic_id = $topic_id AND anonymous_index > 0)
                                    OR (topic_id = $topic_id AND is_anonymous = 1)";

            $result = array();
            $result = $this->db->sql_query($anon_index_query);

            $poster_index = ((int) $this->db->sql_fetchfield('anon_index')) + 1;

            $this->db->sql_freeresult($result);
            unset($result);
    }

    return (($poster_index == 0) ? 1 : $poster_index);
```

I've tested this myself and it works just fine.  There are no index repeats.  Though in practice, sometimes two different users posting anonymously in a topic will have the same anonymous index.

expected:

> --post_id - - - user_id - - - is_anonymous - - - anonymous_index
>
> 1                  12                  true                        1
>
> 2                  23                  true                        2
>
> 3                  12                  true                        1
>
> 4                  23                  true                        2
>
> 5                  34                  true                        3

real results (something like this anyways):

> --post_id - - - user_id - - - is_anonymous - - - anonymous_index
>
> 1             12             true               1
>
> 2             12             true               2
>
> 3             23             true               2
>
> 4             12             true               3
>
> 5             34             true               3

Comment: this isnt formatted right in the comment, ill edit the OP

Comment: Ok, I tried my best to provide some sample data

Comment: Please define "unique anonymous index".